# What is the proper naming convention for Racket boolean parameters?

Tags: racket, naming-conventions, conventions

If we have a boolean defining whether to auto-accept or not, we'd call it `auto-accept?`. If we have a parameter defining some color we would call it `color-param`. How would we call the parameter that defines a boolean? `auto-accept?-param` because it is a 'parametrised' boolean? `auto-accept-param?` or even just `auto-accept-param` because a parameter is a parameter, and not a boolean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very common to use the prefix `current-` to name parameters.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=current-

It's fairly common to append a question mark for parameters that holds a boolean value. In the list from above you see names such as:

```
current-any-type? 
current-cache-all?
etc
```

The full list of such parameters (long):

http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=current?

I suggest: `currect-auto-accept?`.